# visual studio outlook plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have VS 2013 Community Edition and I want to develop Outlook add-in.

In the "New Project" window, I don't see anything about Outlook or Office add-in (in Installed or Online Templates).

Where can I found the missing Templates (maybe in vsix format) ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access `Office/Sharepoint`

Select `Office Add-in section`

Click on `OUtlook 2013 Add-in`

link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/fp161135.aspx

Comment: we can't find that option when i open visual studio community edition 2013

Comment: you need to download template .